# Google play repetitive content

Tags: android, google-play, policy

In Google play TOS and Content Policy there is a line that states `Do not post repetitive content`.
If I have 2 identical apps(same code, same UI) but with 2 different names, am I in violation of Google Play Content Policy? Will one of the apps be removed, or both? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could just try it and see. Also, why would you post identical apps with different names? Only reason I can see for that is one app is paid and the other is free..

Comment: @rascuache I am asking because I don't want Google to disable my whole account.

Comment: I wouldn't be too worried about it. If there's an issue your APK will probably just fail to upload. Also, IslandCow is right, you need to specify a different package name for each app.

Comment: @rascuache Of course there are different package names, but both apps are doing the same thing, look the same. There isn't a problem with uploading them, I dont know if they will be removed when they sweep the market for duplicate content.

Comment: @rascuache Also, do you know how many google play accounts can one developer have? Is there a limit?

Comment: No, I don't. There is a reason Google don't want duplicate code on Google Play. If you're trying to create a paid and free version, there's nothing to worry about. If not, then it sounds like you're either ripping off someone else's app, or spamming apps to the Play Store. I recommend that you don't do either of those things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not upload identical or very-very-very similar items.

E.g. you should not spam the play store. Do not upload an app that does one thing, then change the package, and reupload it again. That is a violation.

This includes changing the name so that it appears different even though it's the exact same thing. They must do separate things.

Edited for clarity

Comment: Thank you for the response. If I make an app that is similar to another(from other developer) but with different UI and added functionality, is there a problem? I see many apps from different developers that do the same thing, some good, some crash at runtime.

Comment: That shouldn't be an issue. As long as the idea isn't patented (doubtful, but you should look it up still) it shouldn't be an issue. There are a lot of apps that do the same thing from different developers, as long as they are actually different it won't matter. If it's an exact clone though, then it'll be an issue, but since you don't have the source code it won't be.

Comment: Be very, very careful. Google is very, very strict with this rule nowadays. I know, because I got my Developer account terminated for this reason. My apps were not even real copies, as they were aimed at different languages. Read this story from a different dev with the same experience: https://android.jlelse.eu/google-just-terminated-my-google-play-publisher-account-in-one-hour-after-10-years-of-loyal-service-7e3185c217b

Answer (score 1):

I just had 2 apps removed, then the less popular one reinstated after an appeal. It seems that if the apps have the same function but entirely different UI (imagery, layout, sounds) it still falls under repetitive content. The glimmer of hope (though not confirmed when asking) is that it might be OK with a different developer account as per my email: "For example, your app appears to provide similar or identical content as other apps under your developer account"

Comment: Thank you for this info, right now, I've the same issue here, since I no longer need these apps, I just modified some UI, changing the store listing on Google Play console, and finally, I've unpublished these apps, is that enough?

Answer (score -4):

For Google Play, you need to have 2 different package names.  So one app would be in com.company.awesome and the other would be com.company.awesome-er or something like that.  That's how I've published my free and non-free versions.

This is especially important since free apps can never become paid apps.

Comment: Yes, but if `com.company.awesome` and `com.company.awesome-er` are both free, with different names in the package and UI title, but basically do the same thing, is this a violation of Content Policy?